# Integrity error owner_id DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created a simple model API with Django Rest Framework.. For the most part i followed quick start tutorial on DRF site. 
I am accessing it from angular app using Authorization token. Everything works fine except when i wish to make a new post...

This is the error I get ***null value in column "owner_id" violates not-null constraint***

This is my code: 
**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    point = models.PointField(max_length=255, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='posts')
    active = models.NullBooleanField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expires = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ( 'owner', 'id', 'title', 'point', 'active', 'created', 'expires')
```

**views.py**

```
class PostList(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check the keys that come in `request.data` with the keys specified in `PostSerializer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, lets take this one step at a time. First, perform_create() method is defined in the create mixin that is used by ModelViewSet. Overriding it in the APIView derived view class doesn't do anything. So your Post creation is all handled by the post() method. The easiest way to fix the error is to add `owner=self.request.user` to your `serializer.save()` call in post().

That said, you might want to consider redefining the whole thing as a ModelViewSet, since you will likely need a full set of CRUD APIs anyway.

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Post.objects.all()
        serializer_class = PostSerializer
        permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Thank you! The first solution did the trick. I'll try the part with viewsets.

Comment: Until you decide to do viewsets you can safely delete your perform_create() since it will never get called by anything

Comment: I spent a good bit of time getting a nasty IntegrityError on a serializer that was called for POST requests in an attempt to create a new instance of a model that had a foreign-key relationship with another model. Great answer.